# Monogame Texture without colors

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I can't find solution for this problem:

I'm using VertexPositionTexture to create rectangle with texture and DrawUserPrimitives to draw some primitives.

Rectangle is:

```
tmpPoint.VerticesList[0] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(-size, size, 0), new Vector2(0, 0));
tmpPoint.VerticesList[1] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(size, size, 0), new Vector2(1f, 0));
tmpPoint.VerticesList[2] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(-size, -size, 0), new Vector2(0, 1f));
tmpPoint.VerticesList[3] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(size, -size, 0), new Vector2(1f, 1f));
```

Effect setted up:

```
Effect = new BasicEffect(game.GraphicsDevice) {
    VertexColorEnabled = true,
    TextureEnabled = true };
Effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
```

And drawing method:

```
public void DrawRectangle()
{
    originalBlend = game.GraphicsDevice.BlendState;
    game.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
    Effect.World = PointScale * PointRotation * PointTranslation;
    Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
    game.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, VerticesList, 0, vertexBuffer.VertexCount / 2); 0, 0, 4, 0, 2);
    game.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = originalBlend;
}
```

All fine, but rectangle with texture has no colors, only alpha channel and gradients of black. It looks like this:
[image]

but image for texture is:

[image]

When I tried to remove:

```
Effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
Effect.LightingEnabled = true;
VertexColorEnabled = true;
```

Colors are working...

You may be confused, but it already works fine with colors on machine with Windows 7. When I checked-in in TFS all changes, and get latest version on Windows 10 machine, I have this problem. I haven't Windows 7 machine yet. But I checked on another machine with Windows 7 executables, no success...

On host machine with no problems:

- DLL's in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\DesktopGL path are 3.5.1.1679
- DLL's in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools are 3.5.1.1679
- DLL's in the Debug\ path are 3.5.1.1679

loaded assemblies(listed only with differences):

- mscorlib.dll 4.6.1076
- System.Core.dll 4.6.1055.0
- System.dll 4.6.1075.0
- System.Drawing.dll 4.6.1068.2
- System.Windows.Forms.dll 4.6.1055.0

On another Windows 10(any version of Windows 7+) machine with problems (no difference):

- DLL's in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\DesktopGL path are 3.5.1.1679
- DLL's in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools are 3.5.1.1679
- DLL's in the Debug\ path are 3.5.1.1679

loaded assemblies(listed only with differences):

- mscorlib.dll 4.6.1080
- System.Core.dll 4.6.1038.0
- System.dll 4.6.1081.0
- System.Drawing.dll 4.6.1078.0
- System.Windows.Forms.dll 4.6.1038.0

Opened issue: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/5029

**UPDATE:** It seems what it only not working on Intel HD Graphics, but on Radeon and NVidia works fine...

Comment: Post your code. [mcve]

Comment: MickyD, thank you. Done.

Comment: I investigated new behavior.

Comment: I'm confused, you say it works and does not work on Windows 7. Which is it?

Comment: I have host Windows 7 machine, where example is working fine. And I have virtual machine with another Windows 7 machine, where example not working. The second one machine, VM system have no installed Monogame Desktop components, just run executables copied from first machine. On the host machine Installed Monogame Desktop.

Comment: Can you before drawing clear screen like:  `game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);` ?

Comment: No changes... After I removing Effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
Effect.LightingEnabled = true;
VertexColorEnabled = true; and it works...

Comment: It seems what it only not working on Intel HD Graphics, but on Radeon and NVidia works fine...
Tested successfully on: ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series, NVIDIA GeForce GT 430 and NVIDIA GeForce GT 240.
Lights not working on: Intel HD Graphics 4000 and maybe other Integrated graphics

Comment: Also tested on NVIDIA 540M with success result and on Intel HD Graphics 4400 with no lighting.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying is the ultimate answer, but one very important thing to check is that you have the lastest driver version for the Intel graphics system.